# Merging 2 request classes into a single class with required fields in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, polymorphism, overloading

I have 2 requests as `CreateRequest` and `UpdateRequest`. The only difference is that, some fields are not required in the `UpdateRequest`. For this reason, I need to overload the following method that takes `CreateRequest`:

```
private void setRequest(CreateRequest request) {
    IntegrationRequest intRequest = new IntegrationRequest();
    intRequest.setLocationId(request.getLocationId());
    intRequest.setApiToken(request.getApiToken());

    // other setters and procedures
}
```

The overloaded method is this:

```
private void setRequest(UpdateRequest request) {
    IntegrationRequest intRequest = new IntegrationRequest();
    intRequest.setLocationId(request.getLocationId());
    intRequest.setApiToken(request.getApiToken());

    // other setters and procedures
}
```

Both method are called from the same class and for this reason, I cannot pass the requests as a generic way. In this scene, I am wondering if there is a better approach instead of overloading `setRequest` in order to use a single method instead of 2 methods?

Comment: Create a common base class for CreateRequest and UpdateRequest

Comment: What does a Request represent?

Comment: Yeah, I had actually. But, the fields that are set in the `setRequest` method e.g. `locationId` is not in the base class. The base class is also extended by the other classes that have not `locationId` field. **In tis scene**, should I create another base class that extends from base class and pass it to `setRequest` method?

Comment: @tbjorch Just a request, not important

Comment: @Eran Amigo? Any reply please?

Comment: @tbjorch What do you think regarding to my comment as a reply to Eran? (creating another base class by extending current base)?

Comment: **By the way**, there is a problem when using another base class. the `apiToken` field is required in create request, but  in update request, it is not required. For this reason, I cannot move it to the base class that I created. So, how can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using an Interface for both `CreateRequest` and `UpdateRequest`?

```
interface Request {
    String / int getLocationId();
    String getApiToken();
}

class CreateRequest implements Request {
    public CreateRequest(String apiToken) {
        // check for apiToken != null and set the value to your object
    }
    ...
}

class UpdateRequest implements Request {...}
```

Then you would only need one method `setRequest` which gets an interface implementation of Request as parameter.

```
private void setRequest(Request request) {...}
```

You can also combine it with your base class:

```
abstract class BaseRequest {
    String / int locationId;
    String apiToken;

    // getter / setter / other stuff
}
```

The signature of your Request classes then would be:

```
class CreateRequest extends BaseRequest implements Request {...}

class UpdateRequest extends BaseRequest implements Request {...}
```

Comment: Why should I use interface instead of base class? I am not sure which one is better for this scenario, any clarification pls?

Comment: **By the way**, there is a problem when using another base class. the `apiToken` field is required in create request, but  in update request, it is not required. For this reason, I cannot move it to the base class that I created. So, how can I fix that problem?

Comment: any reply pls regarding to these 2 issues?

Comment: @Upvoters Any reply instead of just voting up?

Comment: With the interface solution you would still have the flexibility to have the `apiToken` required in one of the implemenations and not in the other one. I guess the `apiToken` is set within the constructor of `CreateRequest` and `UpdateRequest`? Then for the constructor of `CreateRequest` you can make it a required parameter. The same could be done if you would use a base class, the information for the required field must be made within the related implementation class.